# What are the valid declarations for html5?

Tags: html

I've seen the following declaration to utilize html5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

However does one really need to specify this?  What actually happens when you use just: `<!DOCTYPE>`.  How can I check what doctype is being used and if there is a default being used with a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What actually happens when you use just: `<!DOCTYPE>`

Using just `<!DOCTYPE>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>` triggers browsers to go into “quirks mode”:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode
- https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/

So yes to stop browsers from going into quirks mode you really do need to use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

> How can I check what doctype is being used

Browser don’t “use” the doctype for anything other than deciding whether to go into quirks mode.

> …if there is a default being used with a browser?

There is no default doctype browsers use. The only default is: If a doc has no doctype at all, then browsers go into quirks mode. The shortest possible doctype to prevent browsers from going into quirks mode is `<!DOCTYPE html>`. That’s why it was chosen in the HTML spec to be defined as *the* standard doctype for HTML (including for all future versions of HTML).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html 5 you should use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

fore on doctype tags have a look on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_doctype.asp) link